# how simulate low battery level on surface 4 with win 10

Tags: testing, windows-10, surface

I have to test application on surface 4 with windows 10. The crucial thing is testing of popup messages with low battery level. I'm wondering about low battery level simulation tools. Is it possible to do it in such device? What kind of solution/tools I can use.

Thx,
S.

Comment: Wonder if you can set the low battery warning to be much higher say 95% so you only have to wait a shorter period before the notification appears - so would be the real notification

Comment: Thx for answer. yes, it would be of course kind of workaround, but still won't simulate the real scenario. Additionally if we have some levels of warning as 20%, 10% and 5% it's still problematic.